# Check if grid is scrolled all the way to the bottom

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

In the current project I have to implement custom infinite scrolling, meaning that when the user scrolls the page down so the last row becomes at least partially visible I have to load another bulk of data from the database.

The problem is to detect whether the last row is visible or not. So far I came up with the following solution:

```
    gridView.TopRowChanged += GridView_TopRowChanged;

    private void GridView_TopRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rowVisibleState = gridView.IsRowVisible(gridView.DataRowCount - 1);
        if (rowVisibleState == RowVisibleState.Visible 
            || rowVisibleState == RowVisibleState.Partially)
        {
            LoadData();
        }
    }
```

That works fine until I group data by any column.

[image]

As you can see on the picture, scrolling reached the last row, but technically the last row is still hidden behind the group header.

Is there a way to determine if scrolling reached the bottom regardless if the data grouped or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can operate with the vertical scrollbar directly to make your code more stratightforward and robust:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        var scrollBar = gridControl1.Controls.OfType<VCrkScrollBar>().FirstOrDefault();
        scrollBar.Scroll += ScrollBar_Scroll;

    }

    private void ScrollBar_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e) {

        if (e.NewValue == ((IScrollBar)sender).ViewInfo.VisibleMaximum) {
            LoadMoreData();
        }
    }
```

Additionally, you can check the *e.OldValue* parameter to check the previous scrollbar state and scrolling direction.